# could_not_write_file cluster_nodes.config etxtbsy

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I use Docker Toolbox on Windows Server 2012. My run_docker script:

```
docker run --rm -p 5050:5050 -p 49555:5555 -p 15672:15672 -m 3G -v /c/Users/Administrator/services/ndvi-service/logs:/home/ndvi_logs -v /c/Users/Administrator/services/ndvi-service/rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia -h ndvi -td ndvi > container_id
```

But I get an error when starting RabbitMQ:

```
root@ndvi:/# cat /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_err
init terminating in do_boot ({error,could_not_write_file,/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@ndvi/cluster_nodes.config,etxtbsy}})
```

When I remove mount command for rabbitmq from docker run, everything starts fine:

```
 docker run --rm -p 5050:5050 -p 49555:5555 -p 15672:15672 -m 3G -v /c/Users/Administrator/services/ndvi-service/logs:/home/ndvi_logs -h ndvi -td ndvi > container_id
```

I want to mount RabbitMQ folder to make it persist.

Answer (score 1):

I can create the volume manually:

```
docker volume create my-vol
```

And mount command will work great using my-vol:

```
docker run --rm -p 5050:5050 -p 49555:5555 -p 15672:15672 -m 3G -v /c/Users/Administrator/services/ndvi-service/logs:/home/ndvi_logs -v my-vol:/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia -h ndvi -td ndvi > container_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all unused local volumes

```
docker volume prune
```